# Taking input type double separated by space in Java

Tags: java

I need to use scannner to take input from user for data type double separated by white space.

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("exampleDouble: ");
            double db = input.nextDouble();
            db+=input.nextLine();
```

I thought this would work, looking for a simple statement for capturing 2 values (both double, separated by space). no arrays. only need to capture 2 values , not more.
Example :  58.0 57.3

Comment: How about calling `input.nextDouble()` twice and storing results in separate variables like `double db1 = input.nextDouble(); double db2 = input.nextDouble();`?

Answer (score 1):

**WITHOUT USING ARRAYS**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class MyClass {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            double double1 = input.nextDouble();
            double double2 = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Double1 is "+double1);
            System.out.println("Double2 is "+double2);
        }
    }
```

**WITH ARRAYS**

You can split it into a String array, and then parse them using `Double.parseDouble` like so:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner();
String[] userinput = input.nextLine().split(" ");
double double1 = Double.parseDouble(userinput[0]);
double double2 = Double.parseDouble(userinput[1]);
```

Therefore, the full code would be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] userinput = input.nextLine().split(" ");
        double double1 = Double.parseDouble(userinput[0]);
        double double2 = Double.parseDouble(userinput[1]);
        System.out.println("Double1 is "+double1);
        System.out.println("Double2 is "+double2);
    }
}
```

**Sample I/O**

*Input*

```
2.5 3.5
```

*Output*

```
Double1 is 2.5
Double2 is 3.5
```

**HOWEVER**: As @Pschemo so aptly pointed out - you should just be using `input.nextDouble()` twice.

Comment: But why? We have `nextDouble` so we wouldn't need to parse it manually. Also what is the point to read entire line and split it later if one of Scanners main jobs is to split text into separate parts for us?

Comment: @Pshemo I'm answering what the OP asked.

Comment: Are you sure? In question there is "no arrays" (although it is not clear if it is requirement of just some side note).